# How to define design parameters for an FMU?

Tags: modelica, fmi

I am trying to find a way to define design parameters for an FMU of a motor. These are specifications like whether the motor is AC or DC, its dimensions like length and diameter, weight and some specifications like maximum input voltage, maximum output torque and power, etc. which are constant and do not play a role during simulation. Is there a way to define these either inside the model description file or as a separate file such that they do not affect the simulation?

I know one way is to use annotations inside the model description file however, I wanted to know if there is a more formal way to do this.

Comment: In case you start with a Modelica model: Why don't you use (final) parameters to define auxiliary variables and just don't use them anywhere?

Comment: I am not really sure what you want to do with "design" parameters that do not influence the simulation. 
You can put any file in the documentation folder of the FMU to describe them.

Comment: @ChristianBertsch I am trying to make FMU models for several types of motors. I want a way to document their "design" parameters so I can keep track of the exact motor I will be working with.

Comment: If you use several FMUs for several motors, you should use the documentation folder.
If you want to have several parameter sets for one motor, you should use the SSP standard (if your importing tools supports it).

Comment: @ChristianBertsch Could you explain what do you mean by the Documentation folder? Is it the resources folder inside the zip archive or something else?

Comment: You can find the FMI specification here: https://fmi-standard.org/
The FMU is a Zip file, with a "documentation" folder. See here for FMI 3.0.1: https://fmi-standard.org/docs/3.0.1/#structure-of-zip